# Show number of edges between two nodes on plot

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am making a network graph from a dataframe, as shown below

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'source': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        'target': ['B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='source', create_using=nx.Graph(), target='target')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, with_labels=False, node_color='#1f0ee3', node_size=150,
                 edge_color='r', width=1, alpha=0.6, style='dashed',
                 font_color='k', font_size=15, font_weight=20)
# Offset for node labels
offset = 0.15
pos_labels = {}
keys = pos.keys()
for key in keys:
    x, y = pos[key]
    pos_labels[key] = (x, y + offset)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos_labels, fontsize=2)

plt.xlim(-1.25, 1.25)
plt.ylim(-1.25, 1.25)
plt.title('Example')
plt.show()
```

Which produces
[image: Example Network]

What this doesn't show, however, is how may connections there are between each node. For example, A->B actually has three edges. `nx.MultiGraph()` will make some edges appear thicker than others, but what I actually want is the actual number of edges between two nodes displayed on the plot. Such that the label for 'B' is 'B (3)' (or something like that).

I know that `nx.Graph.number_of_edges()` can tell me the amount edges between nodes, but I want to display the number of edges between two nodes as a count on the plot programmatically.

Comment: The question is *how* you want it displayed.  Do you want to see a count next to each edge, multiple arcs, or some other representation?

Comment: @Prune I think ideally there would just be a count. Multiple arcs could get messy.

Comment: You've said that you know how to get a count.  Print that at the midpoint of each edge.  Offset as appropriate.  Doesn't that not work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels` to label edges. Provide a dictionary with edges as keys and number of edges as value:

```
counts = df.groupby('source')['target'].value_counts().to_dict()
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=counts)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your dataframe to include the edge numbers in your target node string:

```
data = {'source': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        'target': ['B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'edges'})
df['target'] = df['target'] + ' (' + df['edges'].astype(str) + ')'
```

[image]